# Error 1005 clave foranea SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Al intentar crear la clave foránea me da error 1005 can't create table matricula

tabla matricula

```
CREATE TABLE `matricula` (
`cod_matricula` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`id_info_matricula` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cod_matricula`),
FOREIGN KEY (`cod_matricula`) REFERENCES alumnos(`cod_matricula`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

tabla alumno

```
CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`apellido` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`cod_matricula` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Creo que únicamente se trata de una errata. Al intentar hacer referencia a la segunda tabla en la foreign key pones alumnos, terminado en s, pero la tabla se llama alumno y no la encuentra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiene más sentido que la declares como foreign key en alumno.

```
CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_matricula` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_matricula` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_matricula`) REFERENCES `matricula` (`cod_matricula`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Por otro lado,¿has pensado en usar UTF8 en lugar de Latin1 como charset?

Comment: Pablo, yo no he encontrado referencias a esa imposibilidad que indicas. DB Fiddle con MySQL 8.0 deja crear las tablas tal cual corrigiendo la errata. Insisto en que se trata solamente de eso, una errata.

Comment: @RubioRic Tienes razón, en la mayoría de las bases de datos exigen que sea al menos UNIQUE. En cualquier caso es una mala idea apuntar a un valor que puede estar repetido. Quito esa afirmación de mi respuesta

Comment: Sí, algunas modificaciones en el modelo de datos serían recomendables. De todas formas, la relación entre matricula y alumno debería estar también en la tabla matrícula, ya que un alumno puede tener distintas matrículas a lo largo de los años en el mismo centro educativo.  El campo en la tabla alumno podría indicar cual es la matricula activa.

Comment: me ha funcionado correctamente aplicando tu respuesta, por cierto cual es la diferencia entre latin1 y UTF8?